# Unable to run NumPy on VS Code

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda3

I have installed Anaconda (with Python 3.9) and Python (3.11) separately. After installing VS Code, I have also created a separated Anaconda environment `Env01` . Now, when I open a VS Code file, I have three available environments to choose from

a) base Python 3.11

b) base Conda 3.9

c) `Env01`

I've chosen `Env01` as my interpreter using `Ctrl+Shift+P` since I understand Anaconda comes with `NumPy`, `Pandas`, `SciPy` and `MatPlotlib`.

However, when I try to run

```
import numpy as np
```

I still get an error that reads

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You need to install numpy in Env01. Activate the environment and then install numpy in the environment. As far as I know the Anaconda base enviroment (if you do a full blown anaconda installation) will have a boatload of packages in it. But creating new environments doesn't mean that happens in every new environment. You can also manage environments in your Anaconda navigator (somewhere) but I have always just done package installations and updates in a command line.

Comment: How do I install packages in a specific environment? Do I navigate to that environment path on the command line and then install it as usual?

Comment: This looks like a good intro just to get started: https://towardsdatascience.com/manage-your-python-virtual-environment-with-conda-a0d2934d5195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install the package?

If you choose the **Env01** environment which is an conda environment.

You have to install package by using command `conda install packageName` after using "Ctrl+Shift+P" and typing "Python: Select Interpreter".

Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details.

Comment: So I would have to install all the packages that come with Anaconda in this way, in `Env01`?

Comment: @newtothis Yes, the purpose of using virtual environment is to isolate the packages of different environments and prevent errors. You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that was why I created a different environment, but I wasn't sure how to install the packages. Thanks.